# ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) Is this needed?

Tags: c#, cultureinfo

I'm working on an Api and all of the strings have ?.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)

What is this doing and is it needed?
What about the other data types such as int or decimal?

Comment: It depends, if you would like to show money or something, this might make sense. For example in switzerland, you seperate your numbers with a comma, in germany with a dot 

If you get the culture of the client, this makes sense, else it just uses the servers cultureinfo

Comment: It just does nothing when called on string.

Comment: Post some *actual* code. `.ToString()` is defined by individual types. In most cases, it's expected that `ToString()` is a shortcut to `.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)`. Perhaps your types don't have the `ToString()` overload?

Comment: Or perhaps someone decided to silence the compiler warnings generated when `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` is implicitly used? So instead of disabling the check, they hard-coded the culture?

Comment: It is a good question since `.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)` on `string` does nothing more than to return the string itself. No formatting is performed. So why the function is there in the first place is a little strange.

Comment: Indeed, if the code contains `string.ToString()` calls, it's essentially a no-op. [Check the source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,2652) it's just a `return this;`

Comment: All of the *strings*? No, that's not needed. As for other data types, yes, that *may* be needed, but not if you're going to pass in the current culture.

Comment: Ok. so I do not need that for all of the strings, since CultureInfo.CurrentCulture is the actual default?

Now, this is a double.
ShippingWeightLbs = model.ShippingWeightLbs

Answer (score 0):

Some cultures write numbers differently (particularly decimals). For most European languages, decimal points are written as commas and digit separators are written as dots, for instance:

- English 100000.34
- Slovakian 100000,34

Integers don't necessarily require it. If you are formatting with a digit separator, it gets even more confusing:

- English 100,000.34
- Slovakian 100.000,34

UPDATE: As pointed out in the comments, ToString() will default to the current culture. This is an issue, because things that appear to work as expected on the developer's machine will look different, and potentially fail, for clients - effectively, you haven't explicitly stated your intentions. This is the reason RS# complains about it.

Comment: And in most types, definitely in the built-in ones, `ToString()` is a shortcut for `ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)`. Which is why the compiler and Resharper generate warnings that an implicit culture is used

Comment: The OP isn't asking what CultureInfo is.

Comment: @adam how should I handle doubles, etc?
ShippingWeightLbs is a double
ShippingWeightLbs = model.ShippingWeightLbs

Answer (score 0):

The reason that tools like Resharper suggest to [specify culture explicitly](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2017.3/SpecifyACultureInStringConversionExplicitly.html) is to be well uderstood:

> Ad-hoc conversion of data structures to text is largely dependent on
>   the current culture, and may lead to unintended results when the code
>   is executed on a machine whose locale differs from that of the
>   original developer. To prevent ambiguities, ReSharper warns you of any
>   instances in code where such a problem may occur.

As in you wrote it so you take responsibility for its behavior.

Also, in my opinion, the default is not good enough any more. It assumes that human will read the formatted text and it uses culture that hopefully is set at the beginning of our process/thread or if not environment default is used. Windows provides quite a few settings to customize how thins are displayed and when applications where more often than not desktop it made a lot more sense than it does now - just use whatever user wants and he will be happy with it.

If you are working on API project and you see `CurrentCulture` everywhere in those calls and the text is not directly displayed to user, its most likely person who wrote it did not understand that - he just fixed the error/warning.